# Conditional Tag With Custom Fields Not working correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

What I am after is to get the Date and title to appear on each Calendar if that Custom Field is filled in; but at the moment, it is putting them in order and displaying a calendar for every child page, but I only want a Calendar and date appear if they have an upcoming date.

Any help will be madly appreciated! - See link at bottom for working example.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
                <!-- PHP OF OPEN DAYS -->
```

```
<!-- Calender Items -->
<div class="calender-item">
<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("next_open_day");
            if ( is_array($values) )
                   the_field( 'university_name');
            else 
    echo '';
 ?>


<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("next_open_day");
            if ( is_array($values) )
                  the_field('next_open_day');
            else 
    echo '';
 ?>

<!-- END OF CALENDER ITEM -->   


</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any idea's then shoot away please...

The way my site is spitting it out at the moment is like this:

http://universitycompare.net/open-days

Comment: You output it inside while loop. If you want to display only one calendar item, then there is no point in while loop. What code you have between  `<!-- PHP OF OPEN DAYS -->` and `<!-- Calender Items -->`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the if above the div, that way it will not print at all when false

```
<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("next_open_day");
            if ( is_array($values) ) {
echo '<div class="calender-item">';
                   the_field( 'university_name');
                  the_field('next_open_day');
echo '</div>';
}
            else 
    echo '';
 ?>
```

Comment: Where do I put the div? Because when I put it in the php it breaks it.  just need a little help on structuring the HTML in PHP, as I am new to this Ol' Game.

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant! Thank you very much - Just a simple problem of getting the Echo's right, I tried this, but got very close. Thank you again.

Comment: Tsiaoaras - do you know how to make it appear in ascending depending on the date, instead of the name of the university?